# Why reloading a captcha image via Ajax GET fails in IE?

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, get, captcha

I try to reload a new captcha image using a simple ajax GET. Works fine in FF and Chrome but, but in all IEs it fails after the first reload.
After deleting the browser cache the request succeed and I get a new Captcha.

I'm using this code:

```
function generateCaptcha() {

 var timestamp = (new Date()).getTime();

requestMappingCaptcha = "/javaWeppAppPath/generateCaptcha";

jQuery.get(requestMappingCaptcha, timestamp, function(data) {
            $("#captchaImg").slideUp("fast");

            if (!$.browser.msie || ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version == "9.0")) { 
                // animate reloadArrows
                $("#reloadArrows").rotate({
                    angle:0, 
                    animateTo:360
                });  
            }

            // setting new source
            var newSrc = $("#captchaImg").attr("src").split("?");
            newSrc = newSrc[0] + "?" + timestamp;
            $("#captchaImg").attr("src", newSrc);
            $("#captchaImg").slideDown("fast");
    });
```

}

I append a timestamp to the new image to avoid caching and I add a timestamp to the GET-Request to make it unique. But after the first reload the request can't reach the mapped path.

I know there are some issues about IE and Ajax GET, but cant find an answer to my problem.. May you had a same problem and can show your solution?! thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  cache: false
});
```

`//rest of the ajax code here`

[`jquery ajaxSetup`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/)

Comment: I was to fast with accepting it n should wait 3 minutes, now you got your score :)